# After software installation: symbol lookup error

Tags: c, linux, git, raspberry-pi

I've been installing "hamlib 1.2.15.3" (sourceforge) on my RaspberryPi under Raspbian and everything
worked great for a while.
When I noticed an unimplemented feature, I downloaded the newest developer version here:
[here](http://n0nb.users.sourceforge.net/) (something like this, but this link may change every day: http://n0nb.users.sourceforge.net/hamlib-3.0~git-6e44327-20140321.tar.gz)

So I downloaded it and did the usual: untar to a folder, ./configure, make, make install.
After all was done, I launched `rotctl` and there comes this message: `rotctl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libhamlib.so.2: undefined symbol: g313_caps`

I thought the package wasn't flawless and I tried to install the old version again. But it's still like that. Also I tried `ldconfig` every now and then.

To be honest: I'm a beginner when it comes to linux, so I don't know what I have done there. Maybe I was doing a major mistake, a normal linux user wouldn't do. Maybe it was wrong to install that package without uninstalling the older version. Also I don't even know how to do that.

Basically there is only one file in the source code, I need to change to the newer version. So, if there is anyone who could tell me, how to make a clean uninstall, I could replace only this file in the source and install again. I think that would do the thing.
Or shall I rather ask the people from the hamlib developer team?

Thank you in advance.